# E_NOINTERFACE on QueryInterface in registration free COM

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com

Following Scenario:

- .NET Interfaces.dll containing interface definitions
- COM Server A in VC++ Project, implements interface interfaces.IA (STA)
- COM Client B in C#.NET3.5 Project, implements interface interfaces.IB

Everything has to run registration free, so the dlls are not registered. Creating an instance A from B works flawless.

Casting A to IA in B fails with InvalidTypeCastException (Reason E_NoInterface).

A correctly implements IA. I verified that by putting a breakpoint to QueryInterface. S_OK is returned for the GUID of IA, and the interface pointer is also valid.

I debugged further and realised that no standard marshaller for STA is taken when Querying the interface IA.

Manually returning a marshaller (i took the free-threaded one for testing) works, so the object can be casted. But as A has to be used in STA, there is trouble later.

I have com to 3 possible solutions:

1. There is a fault in my manifest definitions. If that is fixed the standard marshaller is taken and it works. (favorite option)
2. I need to manually create the the standard marshaller and hand that over when A is asked for a marshaller
3. I need to implement a custom marshaller (least desirable option).

Are there any other possibilities? What could be wrong with my Manifests?

The Manifests:

```
Interfaces.dll:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" name="Interfaces"/>
  <file name="Interfaces.dll">
    <typelib tlbid="{[The_tlbid]}"
      version="1.0" helpdir=""/>
    <comClass
      progid="DummyClass"
      clsid="{[dummyClass_clsid]}"
      threadingModel="Apartment" />
  </file>
  <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
      name="IA" 
      iid="{[IA_IID]}"
      proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
      baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
      tlbid = "{[The_tlbid]}"  />
  <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
      name="IB" 
      iid="{[IB_IID]}"
      proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
      baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
      tlbid = "{[The_tlbid]}"  />
```

```
A.dll

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="A" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>
       ... dependencies here ...
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Interfaces" version="1.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <file name="A.dll" hashalg="SHA1">
        <comClass clsid="{[A_CLSID]}" tlbid="{[ALIB_TLBID]}" description="A Class" threadingModel="Apartment" progid="A.ClassName">
            <progid>A.A.1</progid>
        </comClass>
    </file>
```

```
B.dll

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="B" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86"/>
  <application/>
  ... irrelevant stuff removed ...
  <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="A" version="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Interfaces" version="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: E_NOINTERFACE is sometimes a threading issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041213-00/?p=37043

Comment: It definitly is a threading issue. But shouldn't there happen marshalling between the threads?

Comment: The `comInterfaceExternalProxyStub` element is not doing its job.  It is outside of the `file` element for some mysterious reason, that's not normal.  And "A Class" coclass has no proxy defined at all.  Whether the OS loader can see the manifest in Interfaces.dll at all is hard to guess, always a chicken-and-egg issue.  One way to find out is to intentionally corrupt it.  Or just avoid being fancy, give A Class its own comInterfaceExternalProxyStub.